# STM32L011: Interrupt flag cannot be cleared in Interrupt Handler

Tags: c++, interrupt, stm32, reset, interrupt-handling

Using the LPTIM1 interrupt handler my code is set to clear the interrupt flag right after entering the handler, but during debugging the flag in the "Interrupt Clear Register" (ICR) is not set to 0 and therefore the program jumps right into the Interrupt Handler after leaving it due to the pending Interrupt bit which is set in the "Interrupt and Status Register" (ISR)

Here's the code:

```
extern "C" void LPTIM1_IRQHandler()
{
  if(LPTIM1->ISR && LPTIM_ISR_ARRM){         //check if Interrupt flag is set
 //   __disable_irq();
    LPTIM1->ICR |= LPTIM_ICR_ARRMCF;        //reset Interrupt flag in the "Clear"-Register
    flag_TimerInterrupt = true;             //set flag for enabling next LED-cycle
  }
```

I found no hints in the internet search regarding similar problems.

Comment: A couple of things to check:  Should the condition be `if ((LPTIM1->ISR & LPTIM_ISR_ARRM) != 0)` (doing a boolean check of the bit)?  To clear the interrupt flag, should you be using `LPTIM1->ICR &= ~LPTIM_ICR_ARRMCF`?  I'm not familiar with that hardware to know.

Comment: I had this first `if(LPTIM1->ISR & LPTIM_ISR_ARRM)`, which was also a "true" value.
There is a separate Clear register where a respective bit has to be set to reset the interrupt bit in the status register.

Answer (score 1):

The description of the ARRMCF bit in the LPTIM ICR register in the [STM32L0x1 reference manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/21/bd/0f/bd/1c/88/40/f0/DM00108282.pdf/files/DM00108282.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00108282.pdf)) says:

> Writing 1 to this bit clears the ARRM flag in the LPT_ISR register.

The ARRMCF bit itself–and all the other bits in the ICR register–are not readable, so you shouldn't expect to get any particular value when you read them.  In fact, your code that uses the `|=` is suspect because you are implicitly telling the compiler to read from that register.  I think you should change it to use a normal assignment.

Also, you are using the wrong C operator to check whether your interrupt flag is set.

Also, I'm not sure how the bit macros are defined in your environment so I'll be on the safe side and not use them in the code I'm going to present.

Taking all this together I'd suggest changing your code to:

```c
extern "C" void LPTIM1_IRQHandler()
{
  if (LPTIM1->ISR & (1 << 1))
  {
    // ARRM interrupt flag is set, so clear it.
    LPTIM1->ICR = (1 << 1);
    flag_TimerInterrupt = true;
  }
}
```

Also, if you are using a debugger, it's possible that this interrupt is getting triggered by the timer thousands of times per second while the debugger is waiting for your next action.  If so you will never really be able to step through your main loop code (the code outside of any interrupts).  You might just have to debug this on real hardware until it works.  You can use GPIOs to get info about the state of your program, and view the GPIO signals on an oscilloscope.  I haven't used STM32 debuggers very much so maybe the timers can be frozen while the debugger is waiting for you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis.
I tried different ways and also `LPTIM1->ICR = 0x7F;` which sets all existing bits in this register.
This also didn't clear the bit in question in the status register but it cleared another interrupt bit. So mysteriously it's not possible so far to reset this very interrupt bit.
As far as I know the timers are running constantly because when entering the interrupt handler the Count value was not the expected one on which the interrupt is asserted on.